# Make Chrome and Safari show cached page after redirect

Tags: javascript, html, webkit

I have a login form (POST, https) that redirects the user to a page after a successful login. (This is done with a 302 redirect in nodejs express)

The next page is cacheable for a long time.

In Firefox and Explorer the next page is loaded from cache.

In Safari and Chrome the next page is loaded from the server.

I want Chrome and Safari to also load this page from cache. (Sub resources like js and css are loaded from the cache in all browsers)

The headers for the next page is:

```
Cache-Control:private, max-age=2592000
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 27 Dec 2014 00:27:03 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

(I also have a cookie set)

If I on the second page open the javascript console, and type

```
document.location='/secondPage';
```

The page is loaded from cache.

Do you know anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

A *bad* workaround is to return an html document like the one below for Chrome and Safari, instead of the redirect after the post:

```
<html><head><script>document.location='/secondPage';</script></head></html>
```

In this way the second page is fetched from cache.